# Tensorflow: OOM when batch size too large

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

My script is failing due to too high memory usage. When I reduce the batch size it works.

```
@tf.function(autograph=not DEBUG)
def step(prev_state, input_b):
    input_b = tf.reshape(input_b, shape=[1,input_b.shape[0]])
    state = FastALIFStateTuple(v=prev_state[0], z=prev_state[1], b=prev_state[2], r=prev_state[3])
    new_b = self.decay_b * state.b + (tf.ones(shape=[self.units],dtype=tf.float32) - self.decay_b) * state.z
    thr = self.thr + new_b * self.beta
    z = state.z
    i_in = tf.matmul(input_b, W_in)
    i_rec = tf.matmul(z, W_rec)
    i_t = i_in + i_rec
    I_reset = z * thr * self.dt
    new_v = self._decay * state.v + (1 - self._decay) * i_t - I_reset
    # Spike generation
    is_refractory = tf.greater(state.r, .1)
    zeros_like_spikes = tf.zeros_like(z)
    new_z = tf.where(is_refractory, zeros_like_spikes, self.compute_z(new_v, thr))
    new_r = tf.clip_by_value(state.r + self.n_refractory * new_z - 1,
                            0., float(self.n_refractory))
    return [new_v, new_z, new_b, new_r]

@tf.function(autograph=not DEBUG)
def evolve_single(inputs):
    accumulated_state = tf.scan(step, inputs, initializer=state0)
    Z = tf.squeeze(accumulated_state[1]) # -> [T,units]
    if self.model_settings['avg_spikes']:
        Z = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_mean(Z, axis=0), shape=(1,-1))
    out = tf.matmul(Z, W_out) + b_out
    return out # - [BS,Num_labels]

# # - Using a simple loop
# out_store = []
# for i in range(fingerprint_3d.shape[0]):
#     out_store.append(tf.squeeze(evolve_single(fingerprint_3d[i,:,:])))

# return tf.reshape(out_store, shape=[fingerprint_3d.shape[0],self.d_out])

final_out = tf.squeeze(tf.map_fn(evolve_single, fingerprint_3d)) # -> [BS,T,self.units]
return final_out
```

This code snippet is inside a tf.function, but I omitted it since I don't think it's relevant.
As can be seen, I run the code on `fingerprint_3d`, a tensor that has the dimension [BatchSize,Time,InputDimension], e.g. [50,100,20]. When I run this with BatchSize < 10 everything works fine, although `tf.scan` already uses a lot of memory for that.
When I now execute the code on a batch of size 50, suddenly I get an OOM, even though I am executing it in an iterative matter (here commented out).
How should I execute this code so that the Batch Size doesn't matter?
Is tensorflow maybe parallelizing my for loop so that it executed over multiple batches at once?

Another unrelated question is the following: What function instead of `tf.scan` should I use if I only want to accumulate one state variable, compared to the case for `tf.scan` where it just accumulates all the state variables? Or is that possible with `tf.scan`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the discussions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4600), tf.foldl, tf.foldr, and tf.scan all require keeping track of all values for all iterations, which is necessary for computations like gradients. I am not aware of any ways to mitigate this issue; still, I would also be interested if anyone has a better answer than mine.

Comment: I have another version of the code that does not use eager execution and I can easily run with a batch size of 50, which is weird. It uses the keras.backend.rnn() function. I have tried using it, but this also does not solve the problem (it uses tf.while).

Answer (score 0):

When I used

```
@tf.function
def get_loss_and_gradients():
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=False) as tape:
        logits, spikes = rnn.call(fingerprint_input=graz_dict["train_input"], W_in=W_in, W_rec=W_rec, W_out=W_out, b_out=b_out)
        loss = loss_normal(tf.cast(graz_dict["train_groundtruth"],dtype=tf.int32), logits)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [W_in,W_rec,W_out,b_out])
    return loss, logits, spikes, gradients
```

it works.
When I remove the `@tf.function` decorator the memory blows up. So it really seems important that tensorflow can create a graph for you computations.